# how to use UIViewControllerRepresentable Coordinator delegate

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm using [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) a maps drawer library which is written in UIKit in a SwiftUI project. I have a SwiftUI ListView that I'm using in the project via a UIHostingController but I want to disable scrolling when the drawers position is not open and to do that I'm pretty sure I need to use one of the delegate functions Pulley provides (drawerPositionDidChange) but I'm not sure how to use the delegate in the Coordinator or if I should even try to use the delegate, maybe I just need to use some type of state variable?

Delegate in the view controller

```
@objc public protocol PulleyDelegate: AnyObject {
    
    /** This is called after size changes, so if you care about the bottomSafeArea property for custom UI layout, you can use this value.
     * NOTE: It's not called *during* the transition between sizes (such as in an animation coordinator), but rather after the resize is complete.
     */

    @objc optional func drawerPositionDidChange(drawer: PulleyViewController, bottomSafeArea: CGFloat)
}
```

This is the UIViewControllerRepresentable where I'm trying to use the delegate.

```
    import SwiftUI


    struct DrawerPosition: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        @Binding var bottomSafeArea: CGFloat?
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }

        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
            let vc = PulleyViewController()

            vc.delegate = context.coordinator
            
            return vc
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
            // Updates the state of the specified view controller with new information from SwiftUI.
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSObject, PulleyDrawerViewControllerDelegate {
            
            var parent: DrawerPosition
            
            init (_ parent: DrawerPosition) {
                self.parent = parent
            }
            
            func drawerPositionDidChange(drawer: PulleyViewController, bottomSafeArea: CGFloat){
                self.parent.bottomSafeArea = bottomSafeArea
            
            }
        }    
    }
```

the ListView where I want to disable the scroll.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    
    @State private var bottomSafeArea: CGFloat?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Button("Jump to #50") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(50)
                }
                List(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                   Text("Example")
                        .id(i)
               }.scrollDisabled(bottomSafeArea == 0 ? true : false)

            }
        }
    }
}

class ListViewVHC: UIHostingController<ListView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init  (coder: coder, rootView: ListView())
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to set up a Coordinator:

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PullyViewController {
        context.coordinator.pullyViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PullyViewController, context: Context) {
        // Updates the state of the specified view controller with new information from SwiftUI.
        context.coordinator.bottomSafeAreaChanged = { bottomSafeArea in
            self.bottomSafeArea = bottomSafeArea
        }

    }

class Coordinator: NSObject, PulleyDrawerViewControllerDelegate {
      lazy var pullyViewController: PulleyViewController = {
          let vc = PulleyViewController()
          vc.delegate = self
          return vc
      }()

      var bottomSafeAreaChanged: ((CGFloat) -> Void)?

      func drawerPositionDidChange(drawer: PulleyViewController, bottomSafeArea: CGFloat){
            bottomSafeAreaChanged?(bottomSafeArea)    
      }
```